# TLS 1.3 Connection with Rust to MariaDB

Tags: rust, mariadb, tls1.3

I try to establish an connection between Rust and MariaDB over MYSQL_async. I get a connection to the database, but someting is wrong. Instead I get this error message:

```
Error: Io(Tls(TlsError(Os { code: -2146893018, kind: Uncategorized, message:"The format of the received message was unexpected or incorrect." })))
```

I think that I have an issue with TLS encryption but I do not find any example which explaines me why. I also tried it with sqlx and get nearly the same error message. I use a standard mariadb database with certificate autentification in two directions. When I use the certificates in MYSQL Workbench or in PHP, I have no issue with connection.  What do I have to change on my connection that the format is correct? I do not see anything what I can change?

```
use mysql_async::{Pool, OptsBuilder, SslOpts, ClientIdentity};
use mysql_async::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;
use mysql_async;


     let ssl_opts = SslOpts::default()
    .with_danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .with_client_identity(Some(
        ClientIdentity::new(Path::new("./src/ssl/client-identity.p12"))
            .with_password("password"),
    ));


    let opts = OptsBuilder::default()
        .ip_or_hostname("x.x.x.x")
        .tcp_port(xxxx) 
        .user(Some("user"))
        .pass(Some("password"))
        .db_name(Some("db_x"))
        .ssl_opts(ssl_opts);

    let pool = Pool::new(opts);


    let mut conn = pool.get_conn().await?;
    let table_name = "table_name";
    let query = format!("SELECT * FROM {}", table_name);
    let result: Vec<mysql_async::Row> = conn.query(query).await?;


    println!("Number of rows retrieved: {}", result.len());
```

Comment: could this be a not accepted [x509 v1 certificate issue](https://github.com/rustls/webpki/issues/29#issuecomment-1453783741)?

Comment: Which MariaDB server version?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I use Maria DB 10.5.17 as Server Version and how can i reed that i have x509_v1 certificates? I use win64openssl to generate my keys

Answer (score 1):

The windows error message (error code 80090326)  isn't really descriptive, it will be raised in case of an TLS alert code 10 or 21. This usually happens if client and server can't negotiate a TLS protocol or a certain cipher suite.

In your case, the server is restricted to use TLS 1.3, while the client doesn't support it.

Rust on Windows uses schannel-rs, which is an API binding between rust and Windows schannel. According to the [code](https://github.com/steffengy/schannel-rs/blob/master/src/schannel_cred.rs#L175) TLS1_3 was added, but it will never work, since using TLSv1.3 under schannel requires a different API: Beginning of Windows 10.1809 (Build number 17763) [SCH_CREDENTIALS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/schannel/ns-schannel-sch_credentials) (instead of SCHANNEL_CRED) has to be used using blacklist definitions.

Comment: The Windows' error message is accurate, because the server sends error packet in plaintext, not a TLS alert 10.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub  Server sends "Content type: Alert (21) Level: Fatal  Description: Protocol version" directly after client hello.

Comment: @Georg Richter Thank you for thad good answer what is going on. This explains a lot. I have deactivated TLS 1.3 and now it works with certificate. What is strange is that my mysql server is showing that he still use TLS 1.3. So what encrytion is now used?

Comment: `show status like 'Ssl_cipher'`; [ref manual tls status variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ssltls-status-variables)

Comment: Hello  one more question.  When i activate TLS 1.3 in mysql it doesn't work, what is strange. When i deactivate it i get for ```SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version';  TLSv 1.3. ``` This means TLSv1.3 is activated?  There is also ```SHOW global variables like '%tls_version%';``` this show me als 3 TLS versions.

Comment: My SSL_cipher is the same for Activated and Deactivated TLSv1.3: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  shouldn't this changed with chaning TLS versions?   But for Activated TLSv1.2 it changes to another one.